# Unable to write files in virtual host setup in NGINX / PHP-FPM running on Fedora 20

Tags: file-upload, file-io, nginx, fedora, php

I have just made a new setup of Fedora 20 on my laptop, earlier I was using Linux Mint, running NGINX / PHP-FPM.

I have been trying to run php scripts that write files or upload files to server, but I am unable to do so, everything else seems to work fine.

I have already tried the obvious "chmod 777" and "chown -R nginx", etc. but the problem still persists.

Comment: If something don\`t work on fedora or redhat in the first instance check selinux :)

Comment: Yeah! I disabled SELinux and it started working. Thanks @mr_tron

Comment: http://stopdisablingselinux.com/ :) You can configure selinux for your needs and write answer to this question with description what did you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with SELinux enabled,

Last command was:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Referred to this blog: http://blog.frag-gustav.de/2013/07/21/nginx-selinux-me-mad/